# "set a style in addons.php" string appears at top of WordPress page

Tags: wordpress

As you can see here https://www.acumaxindex.com/solutions/humanresources/ there is just a string printed at the beginning of the page saying "set a style in addons.php."

I created this page by cloning https://www.acumaxindex.com/solutions/engague/ and I've only changed text on the page so far. It only happens on the new page and I have no idea why or where to look. I know next to nothing about WordPress and I'm new to it.

How can I remove this?

Comment: This looks like a line that was previously commented out in the code. There is no way to remove it without looking at the code of your wordpress theme, I would start looking in the `header.php` file.

Comment: You're right there is an echo in there. I tried to edit it using wordpress itself but it won't upload the changes for whatever reason. I can't find the file to edit in the linux server. I assumed it would be in wp-includes but I don't see it. In wordpress its includes/styles/pages/addons-styles.php